# Nginx, Uwsgi, Django Issue

Tags: python, linux, django, nginx, uwsgi

I am trying to run a django site with nginx and uwsgi. All configurations seem correct to me and uwsgi and nginx show no errors. But the site still doesnt load. It seems nginx is not reading the conf file at all. Here are further details
Project directory:

```
/var/www/myproject/
/var/www/myproject/myapp
/var/www/myproject/myproject/settings.py
/var/www/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
```

Nginx Conf:

```
upstream django {
 server 127.0.0.1:8001;}
server {   
listen      8181;
server_name 0.my.ip.0
charset     utf-8;
client_max_body_size 75M;
location /media  {
alias /var/www/myproject/media;
}
location /static {
    alias /var/www/myproject/static;
}
location / {
    uwsgi_pass  django;
    include     uwsgi_params;
}}
```

UWSGI:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir           = /var/www/myproject/
module          = myproject.wsgi:application
master          = true
processes       = 5
max-requests    =5000
socket          = 127.0.0.1:8001
chmod-socket    = 664
vacuum          = true
daemonize=/my/log/file.log
```

Im starting uwsgi like this

```
sudo uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid www-data --gid www-data
```

And this is the output:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.11.1 (64bit) on [Sat Aug 15 12:51:58 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.4 on 15 August 2015 03:50:24
os: Linux-3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015
nodename: ip-172-31-27-238
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /var/www/myproject
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
setgid() to 33
setuid() to 33
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 7862
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
*** starting uWSGI Emperor ***
*** has_emperor mode detected (fd: 6) ***
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from myproject.ini
Sat Aug 15 12:51:59 2015 - [emperor] vassal myproject.ini has been spawned
Sat Aug 15 12:51:59 2015 - [emperor] vassal myproject.ini is ready to accept         requests
```

my conf file for uwsgi has symlink in `/etc/uwsgi/vassals` and nginx conf has symlink in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` where it had a `default` file which served welcome page but i removed it too. Nothing shows in nginx access.log and error.log which i can use to debug and in browser when i open myip:8181, nothing shows.

Please have a look at conf and let me know what could be the issue or how to debug it.

**EDIT:**
Above settings are correct and the problem was the ports i was trying were blocked :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that there is no firewall blocking 8181 port from access.

Additionally ensure that 8181 port is listening by nginx service.

netstat -ntpua|grep 8181

Comment: sudo netstat -ntpua|grep 8181 returns nothing. But most probably you are right, the site works only if i have `server {
 listen 80 default_server;
 listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;` as server settings. Any idea why?

Comment: You could consider using a socket instead of port 8181